# fail rollback in php artisan migrate:rollback

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-artisan, artisan-migrate

I use `Windows 8` to develop the application but I didn't install the web server or `mySql` server on it. What I do is use the **github** to store the code and `git pull` it on the actual server.

Whenever I run `php artisan make:model` on windows 8, I notice it will create a model file and a migration file automatically. Later I push it to github and pull it on the production server and run `php artisan migrate`, it went smoothly without any error. But when I try to roll it back, the production server will produce the error saying it couldn't find the class.

Do you think my flow of work is correct when I push and pull it from github? What is the appropriate flow for this? Do i have to run `php artisan make:model' on the production server first and push it back to github and later pull it back on my local machine?

thanks

Muhaimin

Comment: I noticed this exact issue last night on my project. I'm using Homestead. Might be a bug with L5 - I'll look into it some more.

Comment: I also notice when run the `php artisan make:model` it will make some modification on some files inside folder `vendor/laravel` (Forgot to jot down the name of the file :p). I couldn't find any article that lead to proper flow if hosting code on github.

Answer (score 4):

Try using the command

```
composer dump-autoload
```

and then rerun the rollback. It sometimes helps.

It is in the docs under running migrations

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/migrations